# Critical Error on wordpress php code when listing custom posts from a category

Tags: wordpress, categories, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

Recently having problems probably because of a wordpress update. This was working and now it isn't. I am using advanced custom fields to grab the category id. Any one know what is going on here?

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'messages_single',
        'posts_per_page' => 10, 
        'cat' => '' . get_field('category') . '',
        'order' => ASC,
);
$q = new WP_Query( $args);

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="series-item">
            <div class="series-thumb">
    <?php   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' ); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="zoom" /></a></div>
    <?php
                }
                else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img src="/img/image-holder.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a></div>

<?php   } ?>
                <div class="series-info">
                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <div class="mspeaker">
            <?php
            if(get_field('other_speaker'))
            {
                echo '' . get_field('other_speaker') . '';
            }
            else {
                  echo '' . get_field('speaker') . '';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
                    
            </div><!-- .series-item-->
<?php    }


    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you concatonating an empty string in youre echoes? `'' . get_field('speaker') . ''` is effectivly the same as `get_field('speaker');`

Comment: You mentioned that there's a "critical error". Which one is it exactly? What does the error message say?

Comment: @cabrerahector here is a link to an example. [link](https://trailhead.church/message_series/grow/)[/link]

Comment: That link takes me to a page that says "There has been a critical error on this website". That's not what I meant. We need to see what the actual error message is (and not that generic error message) so that we can help. See [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) to learn how to find what the actual error is (are).

Comment: Thanks for the info @Cabrerahector after using query monitor to debug I found that this line needed ''

'order' => 'ASC',